# Laravel 5.7 Queue function but not send email

Tags: laravel, email, queue, markdown

i have created a notification with ShouldQueue and my "job" table is populated but, when i launch a command: "php artisan queue:listen" the rows in table are processed but not send the email.

If don't use the queue all code function and email are send to destination.

I use the markdown for send email.

Command:

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

//
use Notification;
use App\Notifications\Listini\NotifyListinoUpdate;

class StoreListinoOil extends Command
{
  /**
  * The name and signature of the console command.
  *
  * @var string
  */
  protected $signature = 'command:storelistinooil';

  /**
  * The console command description.
  *
  * @var string
  */


  /**
  * Create a new command instance.
  *
  * @return void
  */
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  /**
  * Execute the console command.
  *
  * @return mixed
  */
  public function handle()
  {

            $details = array(
              'day_listino' => 'today',
              'email' => 'email@email.com'
            );



            Notification::send($details, new NotifyListinoUpdate($details));


    dd('OK'); 
  }
}
```

Notification -> NotifyListinoUpdate

```
namespace App\Notifications\Listini;

// use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
// use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
//
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class NotifyListinoUpdate extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    // use Queueable;
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private $details;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($details)
    {
        $this->details = $details;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {

        return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject('Notifica - '.$this->details['day_listino'])
        ->markdown('mail.admin.listino_update',['details'=> $this->details]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run the Queue worker using following command:

```
php artisan queue:work
```

Check the documentation on:

[Running Queue Workers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#running-the-queue-worker)

Comment: Have you set your queue connection to

QUEUE_CONNECTION=database 
in .env file?

Comment: And also run these commands :

php artisan queue:table
php artisan migrate

Comment: Yes i have just exec queue:table and migrate. And i have set QUEUE_DRIVER=database in .env file!

Comment: If set QUEUE_CONNECTION=database the problem is the same.

Comment: You have to keep running "php artisan queue:work" while sending email.

Comment: the command "php artisan queue:work" process the queue but not send email.

Comment: Then maybe it will be throwing some error. You can check by sending email without queue that if its error-free.